# JQuery row in table does not get deleted in callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamically created grid that contains a delete button.
In my Jquery I make an Ajax call to the server to delete the row of data from the database.
If successful I then want to remove the row from the table.
However it is the final part; remove the row from the table that is not working.
Can you see why this is?

```
$(".deleteSor").click(function () {
    var deleteUrl = GetHiddenField("msurvey-sor-delete-url");
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var sorId = row.data("msurvey-sor-id");
    var sorCode = row.data("msurvey-sor-code");
    var briefDescription = row.data("msurvey-sor-brief-description");
    var message = "Are you sure you want to delete this SOR: {0} - {1}?".format(sorCode, briefDescription);
    if (confirm(message)) {
        dataService.deleteSor(sorId, row, removeRow, deleteUrl);
    }
});

var dataService = new function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var deleteSor = function(sorId, row, callback, url) {
        $.get(url, { sorId: sorId }, function(data) {
            callback(data, row);
        });
    };

    return {
        deleteSor: deleteSor
    };
}();

var removeRow = function (data, row) {
    if (data.Error) {
        alert(data.ErrorMessage);
    } else {
        $("#message").text(data.SuccessMessage);
        row.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Although I am using a button tag there seemed to be some other postback event that followed the click event.
So I prevented that with this code;

```
$(".deleteSor").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
```